# Why N>T is required on system GMM estimations?

Tags: econometrics, statistics, applied-econometrics

My question is why N>T is required when working with dynamic panel estimations based on system GMM, such as xtdpdsys at stata. Is that based on the potential lost of information due to orthogonal deviations?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps some parameters are allowed to vary by time period.

Answer (score 2):

Asymptotics are done as N goes to infinity and not T. If T is larger than N, this assumption is odd. True for most of what is commonly called panel data estimators.

Comment: Your point is good (+1), but I am not sure that this is the true reason (why several software do not compute it numerically). I have the feeling that it is related to the rank of the weighting matrix $W$.

Comment: This looks related but I'm not sure if its helpful. https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1412035